# i can't delete component in CRUD app on button click

Tags: reactjs

trying to delete component on button click

i have added unique id to component but i cant access it

this is my main parent component, and i am trying to delete the Person Component on click of remove button

```
class MyFriends extends Component{

  state = {
    persons: [],
  }

   async componentDidMount( ){
     let response = await axios(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1`)
     this.setState(prevState => ({
       persons: [...prevState.persons, ...response.data.results]
     }))
  }

   update = async () => {
    const response = await axios(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=1`)

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      persons: [...prevState.persons, ...response.data.results]
    }))

  }


  handleDelete = (e) => {
    const test = this.state.persons.splice(-1)
    let oare = this.state.persons.filter( i => i !== test)
    this.setState({
      persons: oare
    })
  }

  updatePerson = (state, first, last, age, email, numar, pic, nat) => {
    const persoana_noua = {
      name: {first: first, last: last},
      dob: {age:age},
      email: email,
      login: {sha1: numar},
      picture: {large:pic},
      nat: nat,
    }

    const proba = this.state.persons
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      persons: [ ...prevState.persons, persoana_noua]
    }))

  }

  remove = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    e.target.value = 1
    // this.setState(prevState => ({
    //   persons: [...this.state.persons.filter(i => i.target.id.value !== test)]
    // }))

     console.log(e.target.id.value)
  }




  render(){

    const test = this.state.persons.map( i =>
      <Person  data={this.state} remove={this.remove} test={this.just_testing} consoleLog={this.updatePerson} key={i.login.sha1} id={Math.random()} first_name={i.name.first} last_name={i.name.last} nat={i.nat}
      picture={i.picture.large} email={i.email} age={i.dob.age}
      />
    )
    return(

      <div className='MyFriends'onClick={this.checkIt} >
      {test}
      <button style={{fontSize: '2em', border: '1px solid green'}} onClick={this.update}>add new friend</button>
      <button style={{fontSize: '2em', border: '1px solid green'}} onClick={this.handleDelete}>delete
      last added friend
      </button>
      <button onClick={this.handleChange}>test</button>
      </div>
    )
  }


}


export default MyFriends;
```

and this is my child component which i am trying to delete, it has a unique id and Key , but i cant access it , to use filter in state

```
class Person extends Component {
    state={
      modifica : false,
    }

    handleToggle = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        modifica : !this.state.modifica
      })

    }
    handleSubmit = (e) => {

      const first_name  = document.querySelector('.first_name input').value;
      const last_name = document.querySelector('.last_name input').value;
      const age = document.querySelector('.age input').value;
      const email = document.querySelector('.email input').value;
      const numar = Math.random();
      const pic = this.props.picture;
      const nat = this.props.nat;
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.consoleLog(this.props.data, first_name, last_name, age, email, numar, pic, nat);
      const form = document.querySelector('form')

      this.setState(prevState => ({
        modifica: false,
        persons: [this.props.data]
      }))
      //this.props.test()
    }




    render(props){

      if(this.state.modifica){
        let individ = {}
       individ =
        <div className='Person'>
          <form  name= 'person' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <h2 className='first_name'>First Name: <input  name = 'person' type='text'/></h2>
            <h2 className='last_name'>Last Name: <input type='text' /></h2>
            <h3 className='age'>Age: <input type='number' /></h3>
            <img className='flag' src={`https://www.countryflags.io/${this.props.nat}/flat/64.png`}/>
            <img className='pic' src={this.props.picture} />
            <h3 className='email'>email:<input type='text' /></h3>
            <button >Save</button>

          </form>

        </div>
        return individ
      }else{
      const individ =
          <div className='Person'>
            <h2 >First Name: {this.props.first_name} </h2><br/>
            <h2>Last Name: {this.props.last_name}</h2>
            <h3> Age : {this.props.age}</h3>
            <img className='flag' src={`https://www.countryflags.io/${this.props.nat}/flat/64.png`}/>
            <img className='pic' src={this.props.picture} />
            <h3>email: {this.props.email}</h3>
            <button onClick={this.handleToggle}>edit</button>
            <button  onClick={this.props.remove}>remove</button>
          </div>

          return individ
        }
    }
  }
export default Person;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with help from kiranvj i found the solution ( thx again kiranvj ) , so first we need to select the correct Component of which the pressed "remove" button belongs to, then apply filter method and compare all existing Components to the selected one , which will return an array with out the particular Component on which we pressed the "remove" button , and apply the array returned to the setState. Here is the code :

```
  remove = (index) => {
  let newPersonList = this.state.persons.splice(index, 1); // the item from array
  const proba = this.state.persons.filter(i => i !== newPersonList)
  this.setState({
    persons: proba
  })
  }
```

i am still struggling to understand how to correctly select elements in events in react.js so if you guys have any material i can read or watch to better understand the concept please link

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I checked out the code you have and the mistake is a little subtle, but the core of it is that e.target refers to the element that fired the event not the parent component.

If you modify your remove() method in the `MyFriends` component you can see the error:

```
remove = e => {
    e.persist();
    e.target.value = 1;
    // this.setState(prevState => ({
    //   persons: [...this.state.persons.filter(i => i.target.id.value !== test)]
    // }))

    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.target.id.value);
  };
```

the console logs I see when I do this are:

```
Class {dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: FiberNode, nativeEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: HTMLButtonElement…}
```

```
<button value="1">remove</button>
```

```
undefined
```

So clearly e.target is referring to the button that was pressed to trigger the event.

To perform your intended action you need to find a way to pass the id of the Person into the this.props.remove method instead of just passing the event.

A good way would be using the `this.props.id` field to gain access to this data.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `e.target.value` here are you are not using any form element in delete. Accesses the item to be removed by an id (person id) or using array index.

Something like this should work for you.

Pass the array index to remove method.

```
remove = (index) => {
  let newPersonList = this.state.persons.splice(index, 1); // the item from array

    this.setState({ persons: newPersonList });
  }
```

And modify remove props of Person like this

```
const test = this.state.persons.map( (i, index) =>
      <Person  data={this.state} remove={()=>this.remove(index)} test={this.just_testing} consoleLog={this.updatePerson} key={i.login.sha1} id={Math.random()} first_name={i.name.first} last_name={i.name.last} nat={i.nat}
      picture={i.picture.large} email={i.email} age={i.dob.age}
      />
    )
```

Comment: hi kiranvj you're answer is half right ,  you're solution  once tested actually keeps the Person component that i want to delete inside the state and removes EVERYTHING else , which is funny cuz it defies the delete button , but you're selection method helped me find the solution which i will post . Thanks very much you helped me

Comment: @dany Not sure why everything else getting deleted. Good that you have found the solution. btw in StackOverflow upvote is another way to say thanks ;)

Comment: i gave you recognition and thanks from the first second in my post (see post ) , and i also upvoted you're answer but since i am a user with less then 15 reputation the result is not visible , so yea i did thank you 2 times , maybe 3 i think

Comment: No worries, Welcome to SO and Happy coding :)